# Change Routing in Zend Framework for SEO

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I am new to Zend framework and using framework 2.0 , And I want user Friendly URL for My Site. Right Now my URL for Contact us page is `http://local.example.com/application/index/contact`  but I want
`http://local.example.com/contact` like this.
My Module name is `Application` and Controller name is `IndexController (\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\IndexController.php)`
Here is my **`module.config`** file

```
namespace Application;

return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
            // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
            // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
            // using the path /application/:controller/:action
            'application' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/application',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action][/:id]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'reset' => array(
                'type'    => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/reset[/:action]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller'    => 'Application\Controller\Reset',
                        'action'        => 'change-password',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
            'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
        ),
        'factories' => array(
            'translator' => 'Zend\Mvc\Service\TranslatorServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
            'Application\Controller\Reset' => 'Application\Controller\ResetController'
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'layout/pagination'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/pagination.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'flash/message'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/FlashMessage.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
        'strategies' => array(
            'ViewJsonStrategy',
        ),
    ),
    // Placeholder for console routes
    'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a new `Literal` route in your configuration, like this:

```php
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            // ...
            // Put this AFTER "reset" route
            'contact' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/contact',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        // UPDATE THIS FIELD WITH THE ACTUAL ACTION'S NAME
                        'action'        => 'contact', 
                    ),
                )
            ),
        ),
        // ..
    ),
);
```

Comment: hey @Ermenegildo, Thanks for your answer and works as expected, I want one more help from you. for listing of blog  now my new url is  `http://local.example.com/blog` (from your  sloution ) and I want same for `http://local.example.com/application/index/blog-details/my-first-blog`  but i want `http://local.example.com/blog-details/my-first-blog`

Comment: It is the same principle. If the route's name you desire can't be achieved through the combination of controller / action, then you have to define a `Litera` route. Just remember to put those routes at the end of the `routes` configuration element

Comment: for detail blog page -blog slug slugs are dynamic ex.  `/blog-details/my-first-blog` , `/blog-details/my-second-blog` so I think I have to  use Segment here, will you please suggest something

Comment: I'll suggest you to read the [laminas-router documentation](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-router/routing/#http-route-types). You'll find all details there. Just keep in mind that you need to use a `Segment` type and explicitly declare the controller that will respond to the request